# CSS - Horizontal overflows and inline blocks

Tags: html, css

I was trying to display the contents of a div with horizontal overflow and scroll (side scrolling). My approach was to apply `white-space: nowrap` to the parent and `display: inline-block` to the children `div`.

I first tried with empty children `div` and that worked as expected.

```css
.parent-div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
```

Next, I tried children `div` with text content and that worked fine too.

```css
.parent-div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child-div">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child-div">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child-div">Child 4</div>
</div>
```

Finally I tried using children `div` with and without text content but that resulted in the children `div` with text content displacing vertically.

```css
.parent-div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
```

So my question is what is the cause of this behaviour and how can this be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the inner divs is all the same, you can find out with browser web inspector, the problem is the vertical alignment, `display: inline-block;` triggers the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) with value `baseline` by default. Add this to fix that:

```
.child-div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.parent-div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
  <div class="child-div">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot I was hiding the vertical overflow.